# Floating element dissapears behind background when container has position:relative

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have boiled down my problem to a pretty simple single file with the CSS included in a `<style>` tag.
The problem is: 
I have a floating right column with a transparent background to show some text and pictures. This works fine, as expected.

Now I want to position a "Site designed by.... " block just above the footer.

I want to use an absolute positioned `div` for this, which is positioned relative to the containing `#content div`, which must get the `position:relative` property to achieve this.

When I set this property, the floating right column disappears, and seems to be hidden behind the background image of the `#content` block.

I cannot find an explanation for this. A workaround would be to position it relative to the footer (in that case the `#footer div` would get the `position:relative` property).

But I just would like to understand what goes wrong here and why the floating column is hidden.  See the links for the layouts without and with the relative positioned content div.

Understandably, in the case of no relative positioning, the text is positioned relative to the browser in the bottom left corner.

http://websites.drsklaus.nl/relativeproblem/index_withoutrelative.html

http://websites.drsklaus.nl/relativeproblem/index_withrelative.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there! Heres a little help to finish it.

```
#main {
    width: 1005px;
    margin: 20px auto; /* shorthand margin for x and y axis */
    border: solid black 1px;
    /* Added background to main instead so it still covers the full background */
    background-image: url('grey-repeating-background-4.jpg');
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 500px;
    /* made the padding here margin, made it slightly bigger to accomedate the right column */
    margin: 5px 370px 5px 5px; /* Margin right should be as wide as the right column+extra space */
}
```

The reason for your right column to hide behind the content is that before you put `position:relative;` on it it is in normal flow, not 'positioned' and so z-index priority is really just by DOM order. Positioning it just made it a whole lot more important; obscuring the right column.

Comment: OK thank you very much! This makes THIS page indeed look fine!
But one more problem, in my production page, the header has its own background image, and another background image for the content section which is exactly sized for this  purpose. So I still look for a way to give the content section its own background image, and without hiding the floating right column...
I tried to gove the right column a high z-index but this has no effect. Any further suggestions?

Comment: Yes, you need some more markup to accomplisch that :) Wrap `#rightcolumn` and `#content` with a div, give it the background image and a `overflow:hidden;` to clear it (read more on that here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

Comment: Thanks again, I tried this and it appears to be a working solution! Even without the overflow:hidden property set it looks fine. I never used this property because I never understood it well, but it appears to be not needed here. Btw I only test with Firefox.

Comment: Well overflow hidden makes sure that anything that would stick out of that div would not show up, but it also makes sure it wraps arround all its child elements including floats. Normally floats will overflow if you don't explicitly clear them or set the overflow property. The link I provided should give you more information about this.

Comment: I accepted the answer but have not the rights to vote up... ;) Thanks again!

Comment: Well, I discovered that the easiest way to do the trick is giving the floating right column also position:relative AND set the z-index to higher than 1 :)

Comment: While that would work it would be a sub-optimal solution, playing with z-index isn't something I would encourage. This is mostly because older versions of IE have problems with that property, if you're not bothered by that, go right ahead.